# How to use re.split() to split at instances of two characters?

Tags: python, string, split, python-re

I have strings that I want to split of the form:

`s = '|0-1|0.0|0.0+-0.0|0.8+-0.8|0.0+-0.0|-2.4+-2.4|5.9|'`

I want to split it at every instance of `|` and `+-`, but NOT `-` on its own. I'm trying to use `re.split()` to do so because the regular `split()` function doesn't take multiple delimiters, but I can't figure out the regular expressions syntax.

I tried the following:

`splitted = re.split(r'\| | (+-)', s)`

as it says that parentheses can be used to match the expression in the parentheses, but I get the error:

`error: nothing to repeat`

Comment: Gotta escape the `"+"` as well: `r"\||\+\-"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```py
import re
s = '|0-1|0.0|0.0+-0.0|0.8+-0.8|0.0+-0.0|-2.4+-2.4|5.9|'
re.split("\||\+\-", s)
```

The second `|` should not contain any whitespace btw.
Also note that the returned list will contain empty strings because of `s` starting and ending with `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you could do that without `regex`.

Here's how:

```
s = '|0-1|0.0|0.0+-0.0|0.8+-0.8|0.0+-0.0|-2.4+-2.4|5.9|'
print([j for i in s.split("|") for j in i.split("+-") if j])
```

Output:

```
['0-1', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.8', '0.8', '0.0', '0.0', '-2.4', '2.4', '5.9']
```